# In Windows, how can I check the executable run by a Service?

Tags: windows, service, executable

The "Services" window enumerates all of the system services, but inspecting the properties of a given service doesn't show what is actually running behind the scenes.

Take, for example, the Apache2.4 service (shown in the image below), how can I see what executable is being run by this service and with what arguments?

[Example from "Services" window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwu0N.png)

Comment: Powershell’s Get-Service command returns an object which also contains the PID started from the Service Control Manager. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service

Comment: Thank you! had only found a solution in CMD so far, but this does the trick too.

Comment: Oops, I may have recalled wrong. If the PID is not directly available it can be queried with WMI - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1574184/2864740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Command Prompt you can use the `sc` program with the `qc` command (*query configuration*) to get this information for any service.

For the example given,

```
> sc qc Apache2.4
```

will give you information about the service, one section of which is the `BINARY_PATH_NAME` which will detail the exact command (with arguments) run by the service.